# File segment/section/record locks in Linux threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, concurrency, locking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File segment/section/record locks in Linux threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993120/file-segment-section-record-locks-in-linux-threads)

I have a multi-threaded process where a file is shared (read and written) by multiple threads. Is there any way a thread can lock one file segment so that other threads cannot access it?
I have tried `fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &flock)`, but this lock only works for processes, not threads (a lock is shared between all threads in an process).